# textfield embedded font only adjusts according to textfield height

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i would just like to ask why is the case that when i use embedfonts = true on a textfield, the textfield's text only resizes according to the textfield's height but not the textfield's width. meaning if i make the textfield's height bigger, the text also gets bigger in terms of height, but not width, can't the embedded font maintain aspect ratio according to the textfield height?

I'm only wondering about this because this is not the case when embedfonts= false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two kinds of TextFields you can modify using ActionScript: DYNAMIC and INPUT.  Both are intended to react to a change in size by *rearranging* the characters, but not *resizing* them. I'm not sure why you are getting this resize effect at all, but I would guess it is related to some problem with the embedded font.

If you want to resize your font characters along with the TextField, i.e. stretch or skew the text, you should either use the `scaleX` or `scaleY` properties instead of `width` and `height`, or create a container Sprite, add the TextField as a child to it and resize the entire container instead of the TextField.

Comment: actually situation is like this
- WHEN I DO NOT EMBED FONTS
  - I set TextFieldAutoSize= "left", if I set scaleX and scaleY of textfield, the text automatically expands its width and height

- WHEN I DO EMBED FONTS
  - I set TextFieldAutoSize= "left", if I set scaleX and scaleY of textfield, ONLY the height of the text expands according to its height